# Visual Editor for DataAnnotations ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, helper

I am writing DataAnnotations for my models in my MVC program. After doing pretty much the same thing for the third model, I can't help but wonder is there an easier way to do this?

```
    [MetadataType(typeof(ArticleMD))]
public partial class Article
{
    public class ArticleMD
    {
        [DisplayName("Created By:")]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Additional Information:")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Title:")]
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
//...
```

Does anyone know of any addons or plugins for Visual Studio that would allow you to select a Model or ViewModel and use a GUI to define all of this stuff (in a separate Metadata class)?

Comment: Can't imagine a GUI tool will make it any faster.  You might have better luck with T4 though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any GUI editors, but I use a T4 template to generate a starter for each metadata class. I got the idea from a [post](http://t4metadatatemplate.codeplex.com/) by [Dan Wahlin](http://www.thewahlingroup.com). Here's the template I use:

```
<#
//     Created by Dan Wahlin - http://www.thewahlingroup.com
//     Title: T4 Metadata and Data Annotations template
//     Usage: Generates the initial "buddy" classes to handle data validation across multiple frameworks
//     Description: I got tired of writing my initial "buddy" classes by hand once my EF model was created. This template
//                  handles generating all the classes and generates the primitive and navigation properties. It also
//                  decorates the properties with the [Required] and [StringLength] attributes as appropriate. Once the
//                  template generates the code you can copy it to a new file and make all the tweaks you want to support
//                  custom data annotations.
//     License: UIFAYW - Use it for anything you want (free or commercial)
//     Made enhancements? Please let me know at dwahlin at xmlforasp dot net
//     To use:
//              1. Add the file into your project (it needs a .tt extension)
//              2. Change the Source CsdlPath to point to your Entity Framework 4 .edmx file
//              3. Whatever you name the .tt file will also be the name given to the code file it generates
//              4. Don't make changes directly to the modified code. You'll need to copy it to a file 
//                 you control or else the template may overwrite changes you make.

#>
<#@ template language="C#" debug="false" hostspecific="true"#>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#><#@ output extension=".cs"#><#

UserSettings userSettings =
        new UserSettings
        {
            SourceCsdlPath = @"YourModel.edmx",
            ReferenceCsdlPaths = new string[] {},
            FullyQualifySystemTypes = true,
            CreateContextAddToMethods = true,
            CamelCaseFields = false,
        };

ApplyUserSettings(userSettings);
if(Errors.HasErrors)
{
    return String.Empty;
}

MetadataLoader loader = new MetadataLoader(this);
MetadataTools ef = new MetadataTools(this);
CodeRegion region = new CodeRegion(this);
CodeGenerationTools code = new CodeGenerationTools(this){FullyQualifySystemTypes = userSettings.FullyQualifySystemTypes, CamelCaseFields = userSettings.CamelCaseFields};

ItemCollection = loader.CreateEdmItemCollection(SourceCsdlPath, ReferenceCsdlPaths.ToArray());
ModelNamespace = loader.GetModelNamespace(SourceCsdlPath);
string namespaceName = code.VsNamespaceSuggestion();
UpdateObjectNamespaceMap(namespaceName);

#>

using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
/*
namespace <#=namespaceName#>
{
    <#
        foreach (EntityType entity in GetSourceSchemaTypes<EntityType>().OrderBy(e => e.Name))
        {
    #>
[MetadataType(typeof(<#=code.Escape(entity)#>Metadata))]
    <#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#> <#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class <#=code.Escape(entity)#>
    {
        internal sealed class <#=code.Escape(entity)#>Metadata
        {
        <#
            bool first = true;
            foreach (EdmProperty property in entity.Properties.Where(p => p.DeclaringType == entity && p.TypeUsage.EdmType is PrimitiveType))
            {
                if (first)
                {
                    WriteLine(string.Empty);
                    first = false;
                }
                WritePrimitiveTypeProperty(property, code);
            }
            foreach (NavigationProperty navProperty in entity.NavigationProperties.Where(n => n.DeclaringType == entity))
            {
                WriteNavigationTypeProperty(navProperty, code);
            }
        #>
        }
    }

    <#
        }
        WriteLine(string.Empty);
    #>
}
*/
<#+
    ////////
    ////////  Write PrimitiveType Properties.
    ////////
    private void WritePrimitiveTypeProperty(EdmProperty property, CodeGenerationTools code)
    {
        MetadataTools ef = new MetadataTools(this);
        var dataTypeAtt = GetDataTypeAttribute(property, ef);
        if (!property.Nullable)
        {
#>
            [Required(ErrorMessage="<#=FixName(code.Escape(property))#> is required")]
<#+ 
        }
        foreach (Facet facet in property.TypeUsage.Facets)
        {
            if (facet.Name == "MaxLength" && facet.Value != null && facet.IsUnbounded == false)
            {
#>
            [StringLength(<#=facet.Value#>)]
<#+
            }
        }
        if (dataTypeAtt != String.Empty)
        {
#>
            <#=dataTypeAtt#>
<#+
        }       
#>
            <#=code.SpaceAfter(NewModifier(property))#><#=Accessibility.ForProperty(property)#> <#=ef.ClrType(property.TypeUsage).Name#> <#=code.Escape(property)#> { get; set; }

<#+
    }

    ////////
    ////////  Write PrimitiveType Properties.
    ////////
    private void WriteNavigationTypeProperty(NavigationProperty navProperty, CodeGenerationTools code)
    {
#>
            <#=code.SpaceAfter(NewModifier(navProperty))#><#=Accessibility.ForProperty(navProperty)#> EntityCollection<<#=MultiSchemaEscape(navProperty.ToEndMember.GetEntityType(), code)#>> <#=code.Escape(navProperty)#> { get; set; }

<#+
    }

public string FixName(string propName)
{
    if (propName.ToLower() != "id" && propName.ToLower().EndsWith("id"))
    {
        propName = propName.Replace("Id","").Replace("ID","");
    }
    return Regex.Replace(propName,"([A-Z])"," $1",RegexOptions.Compiled).Trim();
}

public string GetDataTypeAttribute(EdmProperty property, MetadataTools ef)
{
    var propLower = property.Name.ToLower();
    if (ef.ClrType(property.TypeUsage) == typeof(System.DateTime))
    {
        return "[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]";
    }
    if (propLower.Contains("phone"))
    {
        return "[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]";
    }
    if (propLower.Contains("html"))
    {
        return "[DataType(DataType.Html)]";
    }
    if (propLower.Contains("email"))
    {
        return "[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]";
    }
    if (propLower.Contains("url"))
    {
        return "[DataType(DataType.Url)]";
    }
    return String.Empty;
}

////////
////////  Declare Template Public Properties.
////////
public string SourceCsdlPath{ get; set; }
public string ModelNamespace{ get; set; }
public EdmItemCollection ItemCollection{ get; set; }
public IEnumerable<string> ReferenceCsdlPaths{ get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> CreateContextAddToMethods{ get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, string> EdmToObjectNamespaceMap
{
    get { return _edmToObjectNamespaceMap; }
    set { _edmToObjectNamespaceMap = value; }
}
public Dictionary<string, string> _edmToObjectNamespaceMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
public Double SourceEdmVersion
{
    get
    {
        if (ItemCollection != null)
        {
            return ItemCollection.EdmVersion;
        }

        return 0.0;
    }
}

////////
////////  Declare Template Private Properties.
////////
static System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager
{
    get
    {
        if (_resourceManager == null)
        {
            System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceManager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("System.Data.Entity.Design", typeof(System.Data.Entity.Design.MetadataItemCollectionFactory).Assembly);
            System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _resourceManager, resourceManager, null);
        }
        return _resourceManager;
    }
}
static System.Resources.ResourceManager _resourceManager;

#>
<#+


private static string GetResourceString(string resourceName)
{
    return ResourceManager.GetString(resourceName,
         null); //  Take default culture.
}



private void VerifyTypeUniqueness()
{
    HashSet<string> hash = new HashSet<string>();
    IEnumerable<GlobalItem> allTypes = GetSourceSchemaTypes<GlobalItem>().Where(i => i is StructuralType || i is EntityContainer);

    foreach (GlobalItem type in allTypes)
    {
        if (!hash.Add(GetGlobalItemName(type)))
        {
            //  6034 is the error number used by System.Data.Entity.Design EntityClassGenerator.
            Errors.Add(new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerError(SourceCsdlPath, -1, -1, "6034",
             String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                GetResourceString("Template_DuplicateTopLevelType"),
             GetGlobalItemName(type))));
        }
    }
}

protected string GetGlobalItemName(GlobalItem item)
{
    if (item is EdmType)
    {
        //  EntityType or ComplexType.
        return ((EdmType)item).Name;
    }
    else
    {
        //  Must be an EntityContainer.
        return ((EntityContainer)item).Name;
    }
}



void ApplyUserSettings(UserSettings userSettings)
{
    //  Setup template UserSettings.
    if (SourceCsdlPath == null)
    {
#if !PREPROCESSED_TEMPLATE
        if(userSettings.SourceCsdlPath == "$" + "edmxInputFile" + "$")
        {
            Errors.Add(new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerError(Host.TemplateFile, 0, 0, "",
                GetResourceString("Template_ReplaceVsItemTemplateToken")));
            return;
        }

        SourceCsdlPath = Host.ResolvePath(userSettings.SourceCsdlPath);
#else
        SourceCsdlPath = userSettings.SourceCsdlPath;
#endif
    }

    // normalize the path, remove ..\ from it
    SourceCsdlPath = Path.GetFullPath(SourceCsdlPath);


    if (ReferenceCsdlPaths == null)
    {
        ReferenceCsdlPaths = userSettings.ReferenceCsdlPaths;
    }

    if (!CreateContextAddToMethods.HasValue)
    {
        CreateContextAddToMethods = userSettings.CreateContextAddToMethods;
    }

    DefaultSummaryComment = GetResourceString("Template_CommentNoDocumentation");
}


class UserSettings
{
    public string SourceCsdlPath{ get; set; }
    public string[] ReferenceCsdlPaths{ get; set; }
    public bool FullyQualifySystemTypes{ get; set; }
    public bool CreateContextAddToMethods{ get; set; }
    public bool CamelCaseFields{ get; set; }
}

string MultiSchemaEscape(TypeUsage usage, CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    StructuralType structural = usage.EdmType as StructuralType;
    if (structural != null)
    {
        return MultiSchemaEscape(structural, code);
    }
    return code.Escape(usage);
}

string MultiSchemaEscape(StructuralType type, CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    if (type.NamespaceName != ModelNamespace)
    {
        return code.CreateFullName(code.EscapeNamespace(GetObjectNamespace(type.NamespaceName)), code.Escape(type));
    }

    return code.Escape(type);
}

string NewModifier(NavigationProperty navigationProperty)
{
    Type baseType = typeof(EntityObject);
    return NewModifier(baseType, navigationProperty.Name);
}

string NewModifier(EdmFunction edmFunction)
{
    Type baseType = typeof(ObjectContext);
    return NewModifier(baseType, edmFunction.Name);
}

string NewModifier(EntitySet set)
{
    Type baseType = typeof(ObjectContext);
    return NewModifier(baseType, set.Name);
}

string NewModifier(EdmProperty property)
{
    Type baseType;
    if (property.DeclaringType.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType)
    {
        baseType = typeof(EntityObject);
    }
    else
    {
        baseType = typeof(ComplexObject);
    }
    return NewModifier(baseType, property.Name);
}

string NewModifier(Type type, string memberName)
{
    if (HasBaseMemberWithMatchingName(type, memberName))
    {
        return "new";
    }
    return string.Empty;
}

static bool HasBaseMemberWithMatchingName(Type type, string memberName)
{
    BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public
                | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static;
    return type.GetMembers(bindingFlags).Where(m => IsVisibleMember(m)).Any(m => m.Name == memberName);
}

string ChangingMethodName(EdmMember member)
{
    return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "On{0}Changing", member.Name);
}

string ChangedMethodName(EdmMember member)
{
    return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "On{0}Changed", member.Name);
}

string InitializedTrackingField(EdmProperty property, CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    string namePart = property.Name + "Initialized";
    if (code.CamelCaseFields)
    {
        namePart = code.CamelCase(namePart);
    }
    return "_" + namePart;
}

string OptionalNullableParameterForSetValidValue(EdmMember member, CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    MetadataTools ef = new MetadataTools(this);
    string list = string.Empty;
    if (((PrimitiveType)member.TypeUsage.EdmType).ClrEquivalentType.IsClass)
    {
        MetadataProperty storeGeneratedPatternProperty = null;
        bool isNullable = ef.IsNullable(member.TypeUsage) ||
            (member.MetadataProperties.TryGetValue(MetadataConstants.EDM_ANNOTATION_09_02 + ":StoreGeneratedPattern", false, out storeGeneratedPatternProperty) &&
             Object.Equals(storeGeneratedPatternProperty.Value, "Computed"));
        list += ", " + code.CreateLiteral(isNullable);
    }
    return list;
}

static bool IsVisibleMember(MemberInfo memberInfo)
{
    if (memberInfo is EventInfo)
    {
        EventInfo ei = (EventInfo)memberInfo;
        MethodInfo add = ei.GetAddMethod();
        MethodInfo remove = ei.GetRemoveMethod();
        return IsVisibleMethod(add) || IsVisibleMethod(remove);
    }
    else if (memberInfo is FieldInfo)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = (FieldInfo)memberInfo;
        return !fi.IsPrivate && !fi.IsAssembly;
    }
    else if (memberInfo is MethodBase)
    {
        MethodBase mb = (MethodBase)memberInfo;
        if (mb.IsSpecialName)
            return false;
        return IsVisibleMethod(mb);
    }
    else if (memberInfo is PropertyInfo)
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = (PropertyInfo)memberInfo;
        MethodInfo get = pi.GetGetMethod();
        MethodInfo set = pi.GetSetMethod();
        return IsVisibleMethod(get) || IsVisibleMethod(set);
    }

    return false;
}

static bool IsVisibleMethod(MethodBase methodBase)
{
    if (methodBase == null)
        return false;

    return !methodBase.IsPrivate && !methodBase.IsAssembly;
}

IEnumerable<T> GetSourceSchemaTypes<T>() where T : GlobalItem
{
    if (Path.GetExtension(SourceCsdlPath) != ".edmx")
    {
        return ItemCollection.GetItems<T>().Where(e => e.MetadataProperties.Any(mp => mp.Name == "SchemaSource" && (string)mp.Value == SourceCsdlPath));
    }
    else
    {
        return ItemCollection.GetItems<T>();
    }
}

string EndName(AssociationType association, int index)
{
    return association.AssociationEndMembers[index].Name;
}

string EndMultiplicity(AssociationType association, int index, CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    return code.CreateLiteral(association.AssociationEndMembers[index].RelationshipMultiplicity);
}

string EscapeEndTypeName(AssociationType association, int index, CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    EntityType entity = association.AssociationEndMembers[index].GetEntityType();
    return code.CreateFullName(code.EscapeNamespace(GetObjectNamespace(entity.NamespaceName)), code.Escape(entity));
}

string GetObjectNamespace(string csdlNamespaceName)
{
    string objectNamespace;
    if (EdmToObjectNamespaceMap.TryGetValue(csdlNamespaceName, out objectNamespace))
    {
        return objectNamespace;
    }

    return csdlNamespaceName;
}

void UpdateObjectNamespaceMap(string objectNamespace)
{
    if(objectNamespace != ModelNamespace && !EdmToObjectNamespaceMap.ContainsKey(ModelNamespace))
    {
        EdmToObjectNamespaceMap.Add(ModelNamespace, objectNamespace);   
    }
}

static string FixParameterName(string name, CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    //  Change any property that is 'id' (case insensitive) to 'ID'
    //  since 'iD' is a violation of FxCop rules.
    if (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(name, "id"))
    {
        //  Return all lower case since it is an abbreviation, not an acronym.
        return "id";
    }
    return code.CamelCase(name);
}

string BaseTypeName(EntityType entity, CodeGenerationTools code)
{
    return entity.BaseType == null ? "EntityObject" : MultiSchemaEscape((StructuralType)entity.BaseType, code);
}

bool IncludePropertyInFactoryMethod(StructuralType factoryType, EdmProperty edmProperty)
{
    if (edmProperty.Nullable)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (edmProperty.DefaultValue != null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if ((Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(edmProperty) != "public" && Accessibility.ForWriteOnlyProperty(edmProperty) != "public") ||
        (factoryType != edmProperty.DeclaringType && Accessibility.ForWriteOnlyProperty(edmProperty) == "private")
       )
    {
        //  There is no public part to the property.
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


class FactoryMethodParameter
{
    public EdmProperty Source;
    public string RawParameterName;
    public string ParameterName;
    public string ParameterType;
    public string ParameterComment;
    public bool IsComplexType;

    public static IEnumerable<FactoryMethodParameter> CreateParameters(IEnumerable<EdmProperty> properties, UniqueIdentifierService unique, Func<TypeUsage, CodeGenerationTools, string> multiSchemaEscape, CodeGenerationTools code)
    {
        List<FactoryMethodParameter> parameters = new List<FactoryMethodParameter>();
        foreach (EdmProperty property in properties)
        {
            FactoryMethodParameter parameter = new FactoryMethodParameter();
            parameter.Source = property;
            parameter.IsComplexType = property.TypeUsage.EdmType is ComplexType;
            parameter.RawParameterName = unique.AdjustIdentifier(FixParameterName(property.Name, code));
            parameter.ParameterName = code.Escape(parameter.RawParameterName);
            parameter.ParameterType = multiSchemaEscape(property.TypeUsage, code);
            parameter.ParameterComment = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, GetResourceString("Template_CommentFactoryMethodParam"), property.Name);
            parameters.Add(parameter);
        }

        return parameters;
    }
}

string DefaultSummaryComment{ get; set; }

string SummaryComment(MetadataItem item)
{
    if (item.Documentation != null && item.Documentation.Summary != null)
    {
        return PrefixLinesOfMultilineComment(XMLCOMMENT_START + " ", XmlEntityize(item.Documentation.Summary));
    }

    if (DefaultSummaryComment != null)
    {
        return DefaultSummaryComment;
    }

    return string.Empty;
}

string LongDescriptionCommentElement(MetadataItem item, int indentLevel)
{
    if (item.Documentation != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Documentation.LongDescription))
    {
        string comment = Environment.NewLine;
        string lineStart = CodeRegion.GetIndent(indentLevel) + XMLCOMMENT_START + " ";
        comment += lineStart + "<LongDescription>" + Environment.NewLine;
        comment += lineStart + PrefixLinesOfMultilineComment(lineStart, XmlEntityize(item.Documentation.LongDescription)) + Environment.NewLine;
        comment += lineStart + "</LongDescription>";
        return comment;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}

string PrefixLinesOfMultilineComment(string prefix, string comment)
{
    return comment.Replace(Environment.NewLine, Environment.NewLine + prefix);
}

string ParameterComments(IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> parameters, int indentLevel)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    foreach (Tuple<string, string> parameter in parameters)
    {
        builder.AppendLine();
        builder.Append(CodeRegion.GetIndent(indentLevel));
        builder.Append(XMLCOMMENT_START);
        builder.Append(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, " <param name=\"{0}\">{1}</param>", parameter.Item1, parameter.Item2));
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}

string XmlEntityize(string text)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    text = text.Replace("&","&amp;");
    text = text.Replace("<","&lt;").Replace(">","&gt;");
    string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    text = text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, id);
    text = text.Replace("\r", "&#xD;").Replace("\n","&#xA;");
    text = text.Replace(id, Environment.NewLine);
    return text.Replace("\'","&apos;").Replace("\"","&quot;");
}

const string XMLCOMMENT_START = "///";
IEnumerable<EdmProperty> GetProperties(StructuralType type)
{
    if (type.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType)
    {
        return ((EntityType)type).Properties;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((ComplexType)type).Properties;
    }
}

protected void VerifyGetterAndSetterAccessibilityCompatability(EdmMember member)
{
    string rawGetterAccessibility = Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(member);
    string rawSetterAccessibility = Accessibility.ForWriteOnlyProperty(member);

    if ((rawGetterAccessibility == "internal" && rawSetterAccessibility ==   "protected") ||
        (rawGetterAccessibility == "protected" && rawSetterAccessibility == "internal"))

    {
           Errors.Add(new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerError(SourceCsdlPath, -1, -1, "6033", String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                   GetResourceString("GeneratedPropertyAccessibilityConflict"),
                       member.Name, rawGetterAccessibility, rawSetterAccessibility)));
    }
}

private void VerifyEntityTypeAndSetAccessibilityCompatability(EntitySet set)
{
    string typeAccess = Accessibility.ForType(set.ElementType);
    string setAccess = Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(set);

    if(typeAccess == "internal" && (setAccess == "public" || setAccess == "protected"))
    {
       Errors.Add(new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerError(SourceCsdlPath, -1, -1, "6036", String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
               GetResourceString("EntityTypeAndSetAccessibilityConflict"),
                   set.ElementType.Name, typeAccess, set.Name, setAccess)));
    }
}

////////
////////  UniqueIdentifierService
////////
sealed class UniqueIdentifierService
{
    private readonly HashSet<string> _knownIdentifiers;

    public UniqueIdentifierService()
    {
        _knownIdentifiers = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Makes the supplied identifier  unique within the scope by adding
    ///  a suffix (1, 2, 3, ...), and returns the unique identifier.
    /// </summary>
    public string AdjustIdentifier(string identifier)
    {
        //  find a unique name by adding suffix as necessary
        var numberOfConflicts = 0;
        var adjustedIdentifier = identifier;

        while (!_knownIdentifiers.Add(adjustedIdentifier))
        {
            ++numberOfConflicts;
            adjustedIdentifier = identifier + numberOfConflicts.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        return adjustedIdentifier;
    }
}

#>
```

This is very slightly modified from Dan's original in that I have the generated code commented out so it doesn't actually compile into the project. When you're ready for a metadata class starter, just copy the appropriate code out of the single generated file and paste it into the real code file that you plan to use for the metadata definition. You can add data annotations there so it doesn't get overwritten on each template build.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any oss or 3rd party add-ins available yet.